What is the ideal time for reaching the airport for check-in?
It is generally suggested by my relatives that you reach the airport at least three hours in advance, and four hours is ideal.
Is there any reasoning behind this?
What is the ideal time for reaching the airport for check-in?

This is not answerable as it is going to depend on being a domestic or international flight, the airport, the size of the airport, the time of day, the day of the week, the season of the year, whether it's a holiday or not, and a bunch of other things I've forgotten about..

Check the website of any airline and airport and you’ll find guidance on this topic. Reasons for it include allowing time to check in luggage, have your travel documents checked if needed, clear security and Immigration (in countries that have exit checks), and get to the departure gate before it closes.

I believe the answer is here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/191113/30703

@PeterM and the specific destination, and whether one has luggage to check in, has tax refund paperwork to be stamp, has already checked in online or not, already has seat(s) assigned or not, travels alone or as a family (or even worse, a group), has any difficulty walking/has kids in tow/has lots of luggage, is at risk of being over the limit for bags, is at risk of being singled out at security, travels in premium class, has status with the airline, is used to airports in general and/or knows that airport specifically...

The short answer is: if you have to ask, then you should be there 3 hours in advance.

...and how much slack you want to build into the journey to the airport, for example if you aim to catch the latest available train, which then gets cancelled.

Airports do publish the time they expect the average passenger to need, usually airlines do include that time, adjusted to the airlines extra needed time, on the tickets or their website.
So if the airline publish 3 hours on their website, as many do for long distance flights, than 3 hours is what to aim for.
Add to that the time you need to reach the airport and make sure you get there on time.
If your relatives know you need time to travel to airport and might miss a train or get stuck in a traffic jam, adding the extra hour seems sensible.
Very experienced travellers may well arrive with less time spare but they know how airports work, often have rights which make going through security and passport control faster and can take the financial risks of missing the odd flight.
As someone wrote in a comment, if you have to ask you need the time the airport and your relatives advice as you do not yet have the experience to take the risks.

If you are departing from Santa Barbara on a domestic flight with only carry on luggage, half an hour is plenty. If you depart with lots of luggage and some children in tow from Frankfurt for an international flight, 3 hours is the bare minimum.
So it depends on a lot of factors. Some that have not been mentioned yet.

In the US having TSAPre or Clear can substantially speed things up.
Higher class of service (premium, business, first) often (but not always) helps.
Having status with the airline often (but not always) helps.
Some airports have another security check at the entrance of the terminal which adds significantly more time. (Last time I saw that was in Delhi this year.)

There is also a downside to arriving too early.

Some airports do actually restrict how early you are allowed to enter the terminal. At least that was a thing during Covid (Lima, Bogota) but I haven't seen it recently.
Most airlines open the check in counter (and bag drop) 3 hours before departure for international flights and two hours or less for domestic (or equivalent) flights. Generally, the airline will take your luggage if there is open counter, but on non-hub airports they may be none.

The airlines do publish guidelines that are often just based on their check in opening times (as that's most convenient for them), but they tend to be conservative and are typically safe.

(+1) I have actually seen cases where check-in wasn't open by the time they recommended (although it was only with low-cost airlines and trains IIRC).


Is there any reasoning behind this?

First, remember that you have two deadlines you have to meet:

The check-in/bag drop deadline. It varies a lot (depending on the airline, the airport, the destination, and more), but is often around an hour before departure.
Remember that to get there, you may have to queue quite a long time: there can be hundreds of passengers on a flight, and often the same desks are shared between multiple flights. Having to queue for an hour or more is not uncommon, especially on busy days.
If you miss that deadline, you are a no-show, you won't be allowed to check-in or to board, and your ticket is likely to be cancelled (possibly along with further flights on the same ticket, like a return flight), with no refund (except taxes). Details vary, but that's a very common case.
Of course if you do not have any checked bags and you can get your boarding pass online or on your mobile you may have to skip this step. But sometimes online check-in does not work, or you have to perform extra steps for documentation checks or whatnot at the airport, so don't discount that too quickly.
Important note: group travel/charters usually require you to be there 2 or more often 3 hours in advance. In that case it's not an advisory, it's a requirement.

The boarding deadline. Again, it varies, but it's often around 20 minutes before departure. You need to have reached the gate by that time, or you won't be allowed to board.
To get there, after check-in/bag drop if you had to go through that, you need to:

Go through security. Again, a pretty long queue, and if you're not familiar with the procedures or don't heed them, it can add more time as they do additional checks. An hour is not unusual.
Sometimes, go through exit passport control. Again, long queues are possible.
Find and reach your gate. Some airports are very large and it can take a while to get there.



So just in terms of queueing and moving around and deadlines, 2 hours or more is quite common.
Now factor in how you get there.

Are you taking a train? What if it's delayed? Cancelled? When is the next train? How long does it take if you have to switch to an alternate more of transport? How long does it take from the train station to the terminal?
Are you using a car? What if there's an accident and a big traffic jam on the road? What if you have to park in a remote car park? How long does it take to reach the terminal?
In both cases: do you know where the check-in area is? How long does it take to get there? What if you got to the wrong terminal?

Of course you may have additional time to factor in:

Do you have tax refunds to process?
Do you need to go to the loo?
Do you need to buy food or drinks for the flight?
...

Yes, of course, in some cases you can be there a lot later. I have arrived at airports way less than an hour before the flight more often than I should admit. But I do that in airports which I know, which allow it, when I don't have checked bags, I already have a boarding pass, I have priority for security, etc. I'm also more likely to do that on short, cheap and frequent flights.
If you have to ask, then 3 hours (target time inside the terminal) is good advice. It will allow you to take your time, do things calmly, have some margin for contingencies. And you may still end up on board having not had a minute to spare.

It doesn't really make sense to factor in how you get there. There is too much variability and in many cases, it may be necessary to get close to the airport the day before, add a couple of hours buffer to have a backup train connection, etc. That's just not what the 3-hour recommendation is or should be about.

Yes I suspected as much and it is generally good advice but the way you would go about it is take the 3-hour (or whatever) guideline and see what kind of buffer you need to meet it. It's important to understand that's on top of what the OP was asking about.

@Relaxed, I live one hour away from my usual airport by train. One and a half if I use buses. There are days were the trains do not run and all buses get stuck in traffic, and it takes closer to three hours. Or you go by car on a normal traffic day and the car breaks down on the motorway, no option to walk away there, you need to wait for help.

@Willeke Yes, and?

Airlines publish recommendations based on how long the whole procedure (check-in / luggage drop, security, border formalities) is expected to take at a given airport. Very often, it will be somewhere between 40 minutes and 2 hours but 3 hours is a common worse case advice when more specific info is not available (for example here is the advice from two different US airlines: Delta, American). That's the basis for the advice you received.
